# Submagmas of natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, natural-numbers

What is known about submagmas of natural numbers under addition/multiplication?

For example, all subgroups of integers under addition are of the form  $~n \mathbb{Z}~$. Are there similar results for natural numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are *semigroups*, i.e. magmas with associative operation. E.g. for any given $n$, the set $\{m\mid m\ge n\}$ is a subsemigroup (wither under $+$ or under $\cdot$). But there are many more..

Comment: I understand that all of them are cancellative commutative semigroups but is there more exact and specific classification?

Comment: They are commutative monoids with no last element.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this reduces to the same problem as that of [Frobenius number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html), which is defined, for a set of natural numbers $S$ whose $\gcd$ is 1 (but which are not necessarily pairwise coprime or anything), as the largest number which cannot be written as a sum thereof. From known results, it's clear that, for any finite set $S$ such a number exists, which implies that any subsemigroup of the natural numbers will contain some set of the form $d \mathbb{N} + kd$ for integer $d$ and $k$.

A simple proof of this fact is that there must be, from the $\gcd$ of a set $S$ being $1$, some sum $a_1s_1+a_2s_2+\ldots+a_ns_n=1$ where $s\in S$ and $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, by multiplying the coefficients by $c$, it is possible to write any $c\in [1,s_1s_2\ldots s_n]$ as a sum of $S$ with integer coefficients - but this admits negative coefficients. However, if the coefficient of $s_i$ were negative, we could add $s_1s_2\ldots s_{i-1}s_{i+1}\ldots s_n$ to the coefficient thereof, increasing the total sum by $s_1s_2\ldots s_n$, and if we repeated this to every negative coefficient, eventually we would have a sum with only positive coefficients; this implies that there are only finitely many value for $k$ in any arithmetic progression $a+k s_1s_2\ldots s_n$ which cannot be written as a sum of finitely many generators from a coprime set, and, as finitely many such arithmetic progressions partition the set, there are only finitely many values not writable as a sum of some set.

From this, we get that if we take any subsemigroup $G$ and let $d=\gcd(G)$ - which is well-defined, since, if $A\subseteq B$, then $1\leq\gcd(B)\leq\gcd(A)$ - then, for some large enough $k$, every $K>k$ will have $dK$ is in $G$. Thus, every subsemigroup is generated by a finite number of elements, and has a subsemigroup $G'\subseteq G$ which is isomorphic to the natural numbers and such that $G\backslash G'$ is finite.

I don't think much more is known about the subject - the above gives a nice handle to study it further from, since it characterizes all such sets as being finitely generated, but given the fact that there is [no known closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_3) for the Frobenius number for sets of size greater than $3$, there's not a whole lot that can be said. If you have any more specific questions about the subsemigroups, I'd be happy to think on them.